# Update AddresBookPolicy AddressLists based on variable input

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to update an Address Book Policy on Exchange Online.
Idea is that I parse some Address Lists and save these into a variable.
These could be passed into the `Set-AddresBookPolicy`.

So I start off with parsing these adresses:

```
$AddressLists = (Get-AddressList).Id | ? {$_ -like "*Company_1*"}
```

This results an array like `\Company_1_Users, \Company_1_Contacts, \Company_1_DLs` as expected.
I apply these with

```
Set-AddressBookPolicy -Identity "Company1" -AddressLists $AddressLists `
          -RoomList "C1_Rooms" -GlobalAddressList "C1_GAL" -OfflineAddressBook "C1_OAB"
```

Result is an error:

> WARNING: An unexpected error has occurred and a Watson dump is being generated: The operation can't be performed on this object because its status isn't valid.
> The operation can't be performed on this object because its status isn't valid.
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AddressBookPolicy], InvalidOperationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.SetAddressBookPolicy
> + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

I've tried converting it to a string (with `-join ','`) and have tried casting it, but I can't get further then an error (which then is of another kind).

If I copy the output and then type it into the command, it works. So that part is correct. However, I would like to automate this.

**Does anyone know how I can correctly provide an input into the below cmdlet and have it running as expected?**

EDIT: added full script below:

```
$AddressLists = @()
$AddressLists = (Get-AddressList).Id | ? {$_ -like "*Company_1*"}
$AddressLists = $AddressLists -join ',' #Adding this line just results in another error...

Set-AddressBookPolicy -Identity "Company1" -AddressLists $AddressLists `
          -RoomList "C1_Rooms" -GlobalAddressList "C1_GAL" -OfflineAddressBook "C1_OAB"
```

The result of `$AddressLists` is an array (System.Array) with contents:

```
\Company_1
\Company_1Country1
\Company_1Country2
\Company_1Department1
\Company_1Department2
```

Comment: You probably want `Get-AddressList |? {$_.id -like "*Company_1*"}` instead of `(Get-AddressList).Id | {$_ -like "*Company_1*"}`. That is, you'll want to preserve the original entry object from the address list rather than just a list of IDs

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried that (and re-tried it after your suggestion). However, the result is exactly the same (error from my question).

Answer (score -1):

If your variable produces what you are saying...

```
$AddressLists = (Get-AddressList).Id | {$_ -like "*Company_1*"}

\Company_1_Users, 
\Company_1_Contacts, 
\Company_1_DLs
```

Then In Theory When You Add It Into a **ForEach** Loop It Should Work Accordingly. I Don't Have Exchange To Test It (by removing $updatecommand and leaving the execution command :o)

**Change the settings of an address book policy in Exchange Online**
<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-book-policies/change-the-settings-of-an-address-book-policy>

```
$AddressLists = ("\Company_1_Users", "\Company_1_Contacts", "\Company_1_DLs")
$iD = "Company1"
$rL = "C1_Rooms"
$gAL = "C1_GAL"
$oAB = "C1_OAB"

ForEach($AddressList in $AddressLists){
    Write-Host "Without an Exchange Server, I'm Just Demonstating The Update Process"
    Write-Host "The AddressList Being Updated Is -- $AddressList"
    $updatecommand = "Set-AddressBookPolicy -Identity $iD -AddressLists $AddressList -RoomList $rL -GlobalAddressList $gAL -OfflineAddressBook $oAB"
    Write-Host $updatecommand
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work, since you're adding only the last object from the array as an AddressList (it gets overwritten each time). Also foreach-looping with `@{Add=...}` doesn't work

Comment: @ITM The Picture Proves It Does Work. The Person Is trying to update the -AddressLists parameter. The other entries according to the poster are static. What was written was to demonstrate.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. However, this does not resolve the issue. My issue is that this variable is not being accepted by the `Set-AddressBookPolicy` cmdlet. And that is still the case with your suggested answer (I know you're trying to help!). I still receive the error that I posted in my original question with your suggestion.

Comment: I see you have updated your question after my post. How does your array actually appear in Powershell (not like)?

Comment: Also RE: "WARNING: An unexpected error has occurred and a Watson dump is being generated: The operation can't be performed on this object because its status isn't valid..." error. I think you should post your entire script, so all of us can assist you better.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the 'full script' and the resulting array. If do a .GetType() of the array it states it is of type System.Array as expected. If I do the `-join` part, it is of type string, which I suppose it should be. When inputting that it just states `Address list or GAL "\Company1,\Company1Country1[...]" was not found. Please make sure you typed the identity correctly`.